# "Fly-in" animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, user-interface, animation

I have an autocomplete on my site, and when a user selects an item from it it is added to a token list on the right.  I would like to make it obvious that the autocomplete selection has been added to the token list.  How can I use jQuery to clearly animate this occurring?

I was thinking of maybe having the text "fly in" to the token area, but I'm open to whatever would work well in making it obvious to users that the token has been added.  Other options include flashing the token when it appears, or popping up a tooltip there.  Would welcome input on what would be most effective, and where I can find documentation.

Answer (score 7):

The desired fly-animation isn't hard to realize.
You just have to use animate with settings of :

1. position:absolute
2. top:(top of the target)
3. left:(left of the target)

on callback you set position back to 'static' and transfer the item from one node to the other.

Made a little example: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/adcvK/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/adcvK/)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a highlight effect, available from jQuery UI.  You'd call it on the new item after it joins the list.  It's a simple trick to use, with syntax like this:

```
$('target').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

Basically, the item glows with a background color for the chosen duration.  The color can either fade in or out.  It's a pretty well recognized effect to show that something has been added.

You can get more detail in the jQuery UI documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Check out the "transfer" effect in the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

There is a fly to plugin for jQuery at git hub which is very handy for that.
https://github.com/s-a/jQuery-flyTo-Plugin